# startIndex can not be greater than the length of the string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to Get the number of views of a YouTube Video but i have a problem on the code, i'm not using the YouTube API!

i First get the source code and after try to get the view count_ but my problem is that i  get    `startIndex can not be greater than the length of the string` 
  On the level of

```
string extract = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(key) + i);
```

//

```
 public string SearchY(RichTextBox richt, string key, int i, string stop)
        {
            string source = richt.Text;
            string extract = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(key) + i);
            string result = extract.Substring(0, extract.IndexOf(stop));
            return result;
        }


// get views
            string views = SearchY(richTextBoxSC, "watch-view-count", 19, "</");
            labelViewsCount.Text = views;
```

//get source code

```
        string url = textBoxLink.Text;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        richTextBoxSC.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: `source.IndexOf(key) + i` should not be greater than total length of string. You need to check the value of `source.IndexOf(key) + i` with string length.

Comment: The code looks ok. Your problem seems to be that `source.IndexOf(Key) + i` is greater than `source.Length()`

Comment: either `value of key` or `i` or `key + i` is greater than `source.Length()`.Please debug and check value of `key`, `i` and compare it with `source.Length()`

Comment: You will have similar problem in both the lines you are doing `substring` operation. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in this line `string extract = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(key) + i);` Somehow `IndexOf(Key) + i` is greater than the length of the string `source`. So you should check the length before doing the `substring`

```
int _StartIndex = source.IndexOf(key) + i;
string extract = _StartIndex < source.Length ? source.Substring(_StartIndex) : source;
```

The above code will just check the value of `source.IndexOf(key) + i` whether it is less than the length of the string `source`, if yes, then do your old operation, otherwise just copy the whole text to the variable `extract`, you can implement your own logic here `: source`

Same problem might happen in the next line `string result = extract.Substring(0, extract.IndexOf(stop));` where you should apply similar validation before doing `substring` operation. So the who;e function should be changed to this :

```
public string SearchY(RichTextBox richt, string key, int i, string stop)
{
    string source = richt.Text;
    int _StartIndex = source.IndexOf(key) + i;
    string extract = _StartIndex < source.Length ? source.Substring(_StartIndex) : source;
    string result = extract.Substring(0, extract.IndexOf(stop));
    int _Length = extract.IndexOf(stop);
    result = _Length > extract.Length ? extract.Substring(0, _Length) : extract;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @DevFranz_Tech - Let us know if your problem is solved

Comment: I have a problem when using the code on source.IndexOf(key) + i;

Comment: i should just make a screenshot and give you

Comment: @DevFranz_Tech - Hey, still having problem ? Please don't get benefit only from this site, try helping other also just by following some rules of this site :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two constructors of SubString

> 1. String.SubString(int startIndex)
> 2. String.SubString(int startIndex, int length)

Now in your case, you are using both

```
string extract = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(key) + i);
string result = extract.Substring(0, extract.IndexOf(stop));
```

Problem is in your first call, where you are just defining value of start index which might be greater than length of string i.e. **source**

To fix your issue, first check length of **source** with **source.IndexOf(key) + i** and then do the necessary actions. example:

```
int startIndex = source.IndexOf(key) + i;
string extract = source; //By default extract is equal to source

//If startIndex of source is less then length of source string then only perform subString operation
if(startIndex < source.Length)
 extract = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(key) + i);
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: StartIndex can not be less than zero.

Comment: string result = extract.Substring(extract.IndexOf(stop));

Comment: @DevFranz_Tech , error clearly mentions that StartIndex can not be less than zero.
Please send us string present in source variable, value of index as well as value of i